# Updating multi header data frame with single header data fram

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a multi header frame:

[image: Multi header data frame]

and a single header data frame:

[image: Single header data frame]

I want to update multi header data frame values with single header data frames. final level columns in multi data frame and columns in single header data frame are same

Comment: Could you please provide code for creating the data in your example?

Answer (score 0):

If same length of rows and indices in both Dataframes recreate new by both:

```
df3 = pd.DataFrame(df2.to_numpy(), columns=df1.columns, index=df1.index)
```

Another idea is reaasign columns:

```
df2.columns = df1.columns
```

Comment: Yes it is same length. I just want to update existing multi header data frame. Is it possible to do without using numpy?

Comment: can you try `df2.columns = df1.columns`?

Comment: I tried that already bro. I tried df1['Level 1']['Level 2']['Level 3'].columns = df2.columns too.